# Angular 2\4 - Unexpected production behavior

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

Shortly, I have an app which is 4.6MB on ng serve.

When I do:

> ng serve --prod

I get 1MB file size.

However, the --prod somehow make my entire application break.

My whole services (promises based) which send a request to the server are no longer working.

The bizzar thing is that simply **ng serve** works perfectly fine **AND** certain parts of **ng serve --prod** works fine as well, as long as there is no server request.

I do not post any code since **ng serve** version works ok.

The main question is: Why do I get that kind of behavior?

**EDIT:** **more EXPLICIT details:**

I am using Fiddler to make sure all of the details are correct:

[image: Fiddler pic]

As you can see, details are ok.

Now for the code which responsible to simulate that request on the client side:

```
    login(uName: string, pw: string, type: number): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (type === 1) {
            const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
            const body = JSON.stringify({ username: uName, password: pw });
            this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, options)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response);
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
        } else if (type === 2 || type === 3) {
            this.http.post(this.loginUrl, { username: uName, token: pw })
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response);
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }
    });
}
```

Now notice how everything works perfect when I use **ng serve** only (Network Tab):

[image: ng serve]

As you can see, I am already logged in and I do get a response.

Now,

The moment I do

> ng serve --prod

Suddenly the same login request with the same details no longer works:

[image: ng serve --prod]

This is super bizzar.

All of my methods which are responsible for server requests are all the same.

**"Bad Request"** with some error code that comes from the server itself (my own server code like "email not filled" which is also bizzar since I do send the correct parameters)

Comment: not sure but do you mind by trying ng serve --prod --aot.It may also happen in production the host url is different.404 mean the service cannot be found

Comment: @brk You are DAMN right! I never checked the environemt.prod address. I was so focused on other problems. Thank you.

Comment: happy to help you